# second scroll bar on this page - not wanted

Tags: html, css, wordpress

http://juniorgoldreport.com/gold-stock-charts/

That's the example that this is happening. I am viewing this on a desktop, and was created using wordpress.

For some reason, as I was creating this page, it added a second scroll bar that is completely useless.

I have no idea why at all. The charts are just copy pasted here is what this whole page looks like

```
<div class="charts">
 <div class="30-day">
 <a href="http://charts.kitco.com/KitcoCharts/?Symbol=GOLD&amp;Currency=USD&amp;multiCurrency=true&amp;langId=EN&amp;period=2329200000&amp;names=,LFGOLDAM,LFGOLDPM&amp;descs=,Gold%20%20London%20Fix%20AM,Gold%20%20London%20Fix%20PM&amp;byValue=true&amp;utm_source=kitco&amp;utm_medium=banner&amp;utm_content=20110407_iCharts_30day_gold_chart&amp;utm_campaign=iCharts" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.kitco.com/LFgif/au0030lnb.gif" alt="" width="450" height="275" border="0" /></a>
 </div>

 <div class="60-day">
 <a href="http://charts.kitco.com/KitcoCharts/?Symbol=GOLD&amp;Currency=USD&amp;multiCurrency=true&amp;langId=EN&amp;period=2329200000&amp;names=,LFGOLDAM,LFGOLDPM&amp;descs=,Gold%20%20London%20Fix%20AM,Gold%20%20London%20Fix%20PM&amp;byValue=true&amp;utm_source=kitco&amp;utm_medium=banner&amp;utm_content=20110407_iCharts_60day_gold_chart&amp;utm_campaign=iCharts" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.kitco.com/LFgif/au0060lnb.gif" alt="" width="450" height="275" border="0" /></a>
 </div>

 <div class="1-year">
 <a href="http://charts.kitco.com/KitcoCharts/?Symbol=GOLD&amp;Currency=USD&amp;multiCurrency=true&amp;langId=EN&amp;period=2329200000&amp;names=,LFGOLDAM,LFGOLDPM&amp;descs=,Gold%20%20London%20Fix%20AM,Gold%20%20London%20Fix%20PM&amp;byValue=true&amp;utm_source=kitco&amp;utm_medium=banner&amp;utm_content=20110407_iCharts_365day_gold_chart&amp;utm_campaign=iCharts" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.kitco.com/LFgif/au0365nyb.gif" alt="" width="450" height="275" border="0" /></a>
 </div>

 <div class="5-year">
 <a href="http://charts.kitco.com/KitcoCharts/?Symbol=GOLD&amp;Currency=USD&amp;multiCurrency=true&amp;langId=EN&amp;period=2329200000&amp;names=,LFGOLDAM,LFGOLDPM&amp;descs=,Gold%20%20London%20Fix%20AM,Gold%20%20London%20Fix%20PM&amp;byValue=true&amp;utm_source=kitco&amp;utm_medium=banner&amp;utm_content=20110407_iCharts_1825day_gold_chart&amp;utm_campaign=iCharts" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.kitco.com/LFgif/au1825nyb.gif" alt="" width="450" height="275" border="0" /></a>
 </div>
</div>
```

there is no extra css I created.

Every chart is separated atm because I'm trying to get them two be aligned in two columns, but that's something I'm working on right now. I have no idea where or why this second scroll bar appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `overflow-x: hidden` from the `body` rule in your CSS

```
body {
  /* overflow-x: hidden;       remove this  */         
}
```

---

*Update based on a comment that only a specific page is to be targeted*

For the page you want to target, do like this

HTML

```
<body data-page-charts>
```

CSS

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

[data-page-charts] {
  overflow-x: visible;
}
```

Comment: but because this is done in wordpress, won't they screw up all my other pages too? Consider I'd just want it to be affected on this one specific page.

Comment: @Robolisk Added a suggestion to my answer

Comment: in regards to your updated answer, when I right click my page and inspect element, the page that I would be targeting is (class) "post-827 page type-page status-publish hentry" or would it be the ID (#post-827)?

Comment: @Robolisk It appears to be class `page-id-827`, so use `body.page-id-827` instead of `[data-page-charts]`